# Win32. How to convert POINT to LPARAM

Tags: winapi, lparam

I need to send `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message.
How to convert `POINT` to `LPARAM`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use the [`MAKELPARAM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro

```
MAKELPARAM( pt.x, pt.y )
```